Why does this C program not return an error?
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[]={1,-2,3,0,-5};
    int i=0;
    while(i++<5){
        a[i]=a[i]>a[i-1]?-1:1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) printf("%d",a[i]);
    return 0;
}

I think it should return an error because of out of bounds i which is 4 before increment but 5 in the loop. Yet it returns 11-1-11 which is correct.

The compiler does not execute your code. So it can not report an error for accessing memory outside the array. But the generated program has undefined behavior.

You have reached an important milestone. Go from reading and thinking about a program to actually debugging it. Use a debugger to investigate what your program is doing, you'll see immediately what's going on :-)

You're a bit lucky the i didn't get allocated past the end of your array, then your loop might not have ended.

C language does not check the indexes when you access the array. If you access the array out of bounds it invlokes Undefined Behaviour (UB).
UB may or may not express itself in some way. It can segfault or work "OK". As a programmer, you are responsible for ensuring that arrays are correctly accessed.
